# Git amend via tig

Tags: git, key-binding, tig

I often use [`tig`](https://github.com/jonas/tig) to select which modifications to `add`, and which to `commit`. I scroll via the patches, push `u` to add, and when I am satisfied, I press `C` to commit the added changes.

Every once in a while I miss a file that I wished to commit together with the last commit. Currently what I am doing is as follows:

- look for the modification I have missed
- press `u` to add it
- exit `tig`
- type `git amend`
- save the same commit message
- enter `tig` once again

Is there a way to define some shortcut, such as `a` (which currently returns `Unknown key, press 'h' for help`), that will do that process and stay in `tig`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can provide custom bindings to tig in your `~/.tigrc`

adding

```
bind status a !?git commit --amend
```

gives you to use 'a' key to amend the previous commit while you are in the status view.

extra explanation of command:

- the '!' defines that it is an external command
- the '?' makes sure that it confirms the command before it's run

the rest is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, via prompt. In your `~/.tigrc`:

```
bind prompt c-amend !git commit --amend
```

Then, in the `tig` interface you can type `:c-amend`.

Credits [jonas himself](https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/808#issuecomment-390366223) :)